# Another user than me is displayed with pop up error message: "An error has occured." "Error: Invalid control reference

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013, ms-access-web-app

When I click on: "Macro detail" on that same pop up window

another pop up window displays and says...

Action Failed

Macro Name:

Home : Home

Condition:

True: [GlobalUserId] Is Null

Action Name:

null

Arguments:

null

Error Number:

2055

Namely when I come to the Home tab in my Access Web App I suppose to se myself as an user, however another user information is visible from the system and I get those pop up error messages mentioned. Note this issue is on Prod environment, in Test this issue does not exist and I havent find any difference in code or structure etc. Even when I backup the app from prod to test, the same app in test still works without this issue. If I refresh the "Home" page in prod the issue is fixed and I can see my user instead (as it should) but this is not the behaviour we want in production. Please any help is highly appreciated and rewarded.

Environment: Access 2013 Web App and SharePoint 2013 On-Prem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not very precise but it seems it could be that your GlobalUserId became null, maybe caused by an ended session, when the user doesn't use the app for a while. You could add guard clauses at the beggining of youtr UI macro to test if the GlobalUserId variable is null. If so, you could display a message to invite the user to refresh the app and stop the macro, preventing errors.